# Merging .count and .txt files using readDGE()

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, count, txt

I am working with gene transcript counts. I want to merge six .count files and one .txt file so that I can do differential expression analysis in edgeR. I am trying to use readDGE() to do this, but I have also tried merge() and left_join. I am able to get the .count files to merge, but not the .txt file. When I use merge() it tells me the file is too large. When I tried left_join, it altered my data so that each column had the same number (ex: every row in column one = 6, every row in column two = 10, and so on).

Notes on the file formats: each .count file represents one sample and contains 3 columns: the gene name, the transcript counts, and a column that just says ".count". The .txt file has a column for gene names, and then there are 16 columns, where each column represents a sample. When I merge the .count files, it turns out to have the same format as the txt file where the gene names are in column 1 and each subsequent column represents a sample.

The following code merges all the .count file together, but leaves out the .txt file. I added a .count column to the .txt dataframe, but that didn't do anything to solve this problem.

```
files <- dir(pattern="*\\.count$")
counts = readDGE(files)
counts=readDGE(samples$countf)$counts
counts
```

Next, I used this code to eliminate repeating row names in each of the data files:

```
names <- make.unique(as.character(countsfinal[,1]))
rownames(countsfinal) <- names
countsfinal <- countsfinal[,-1] # get rid of old names
countsfinal <- subset(countsfinal[,-18]) #get rid of a column that just contains ".count"
```

and this code to try to merge them:

```
files <- c(countsfinal, ML1,ML2,ML3,MS1,MS2,MS3)
counts = readDGE(files)
counts=readDGE(samples$countf)$counts
counts
```

I get this error message after "counts = readDGE(files)":

```
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file 'c(6, 22, 5, 47, 2, 0, 222, 93, 112, 283, 83, 115, 127, 206, 290, 73, 27, 0, 0, 0, 0, 227, 96, 59, 338, 25, 3, 0, 2, 5, 55, 63, 568, 0, 218, 61, 3, 8, 0, 2, 35, 55, 0, 1, 42, 417, 4, 14, 0, 13, 32, 0, 0, 32, 1421, 68, 94, 1832, 70, 155, 217, 62, 0, 8, 0, 52, 71, 9, 109, 25, 0, 0, 125, 217, 28, 336, 364, 38, 49, 89, 133, 25, 0, 2, 52, 1, 20, 7, 21, 9, 129, 13, 72, 28, 8, 5, 1, 388, 172, 0, 12, 159, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 3, 505, 1, 4, 0, 8, 0, 435, 35, 35, 4, 0, 0, 41, 24, 2, 4, 22, 0, 1, 56, 2, 40, 
36, 0, 0, 2193, 12, 98, 3, 0, 0, 96, 71, 16, 1, 1083, 3, 0, 0, 159, 218, 11, 4, 263, 9, 68, 296, 20, 174, 0, 444, 67, 9, 26, 0, 1, 31, 7, 3, 60, 9, 6, 0, 18, 21, 6, 5, 0, 0, 0, 55, 12, 21, 0, 22, 16, 8, 3, 0, 0, 130, 13, 66, 0, 4, 2, 1, 4, 112, 1, 0, 0, 0, 159, 4, 2, 364, 0, 91, 2, 50, 0, 94, 118, 0, 10, 15, 1, 2, 178, 3, 57, 308, 31, 0, 3, 164, 109, 147, 134, 160, 2, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 272, 23, 27, 218, 0, 1, 423, 120, 449, 1026, 125, 8, 0, 1372, 86, 231, 143, 47, 10 [... truncated]
```

I can open all the files I'm trying to merge directly from the environment. I also checked that my files are all in the same directory that I'm working in. Everything I found online says this error is because R can't find the files I'm trying to merge, but I don't understand how it lost them when they're stored in the environment.

Next, I tried merge():

```
counts <- merge(countsfinal,ML1, all.x = TRUE, all.y = TRUE)
```

and get this error message:

```
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 1.9 Gb
```

I tried cleaning out my environment to only contain the necessary files, but that didn't fix this problem.

Then, I tried left_join (a function I've never used before and honestly don't understand even after watching a tutorial):

```
counts <- left_join(countsfinal,ML1, by = c("MSV13HK" = "V2")) #MSV13HK is the last column in the first df, V2 is the only column with transcript counts in the second df
```

I didn't get an error message, but it completely changed my data to make it uniform.

```
MLV01SP MLV02HK MLV05HK MLV05SP MLV10HK MLV16HK MLV16SP MSV01HK MSV01SP MSV03HK MSV03SP
1        6       4      30      27       6      20      20       2       2       7       6
2        6       4      30      27       6      20      20       2       2       7       6
3        6       4      30      27       6      20      20       2       2       7       6
4        6       4      30      27       6      20      20       2       2       7       6
5        6       4      30      27       6      20      20       2       2       7       6
6        6       4      30      27       6      20      20       2       2       7       6
7        6       4      30      27       6      20      20       2       2       7       6
8        6       4      30      27       6      20      20       2       2       7       6
9        6       4      30      27       6      20      20       2       2       7       6
10       6       4      30      27       6      20      20       2       2       7       6
11       6       4      30      27       6      20      20       2       2       7       6
12       6       4      30      27       6      20      20       2       2       7       6
```

I've also tried variations of subset() to try to move one column over at a time, but I can't seem to get it to format correctly:

```
ML01SP <- subset(countsfinal, [,2])
Error: unexpected '[' in "ML01SP <- subset(countsfinal, ["
```

```
ML01SP <- subset(countsfinal, ML01SP)
Error in subset.data.frame(countsfinal, ML01SP) : 
  'subset' must be logical
```

```
ML01SP <- subset(countsfinal, "ML01SP")
Error in subset.data.frame(countsfinal, "ML01SP") : 
  'subset' must be logical
```

```
 ML01SP <- subset(countsfinal[,2])
Error in subset.default(countsfinal[, 2]) : 
  argument "subset" is missing, with no default
```

I just tried this:

```
ML1 <- ML1$V2
length(countsfinal) <- length(ML1) #to make the df equal lengths, they were off by one row
countsfinal_ML1 <- cbind(countsfinal, ML1)
```

And it instead of adding a column onto the end of the table, it concatenated all of my samples from the first df and added one column from the second df. It basically reduced my table from 16 columns down to three.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGfdA.png)

Merging this data should be the last big hurdle in a class project I'm working on. I already have the script written out for the actual analysis, and was able to run through the script on each of the datasets independently. I spent ~4 hours trying to merge the data yesterday and another two this morning. Please help!!

Comment: My guess is that you don’t want a “join” or “merge”, but rather an “append” or an “rbind”. You need to describe what the data represents. I’m guessing (again) that these are independent measurements and you basically want to stack the count files on top of each other. And the txt file needs to be reshaped from wide to long format.

Comment: In the txt file, each column represents one sample, and each row represents one gene. It tells you how many transcripts for each gene are in each sample. The same information is in the count files, but there is only one sample in each count file. How would "append" or "rbind" merge the files? Would the samples still be in independent columns? That's the format I need to run the rest of the analysis script

Comment: The `readDGE` does merging of count files, but you will need to look at the structure of the result and compare to the structure of the ‘txt’ file that you import to R with `read.table`. If those two files share expression product names then you will need to “merge” but you will need to offer us a complete description of the structures of those two files.

Comment: Also. There is a Bioinformatics forum on SE https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/ as well as the Bioconductor support list.